# Laravel 5.3 :How To use Check Auth in Global Middleware?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I want show the number of unread messages in the header of my site and a few other views. For this I wrote a global middleware, but this middleware can not access of auth info of the signed up user.

```php
<?php

namespace PTA_OIMS\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\View\Factory;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use PTA_OIMS\Kartable;
use Session;

class UnreadMessage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    protected $auth;
    protected $view;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Factory $view)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $unreadMessage = NULL;
        $user = $this->auth->check();
        if (!empty($user)) {
            $unreadMessage = Kartable::
            where('id_reciver', '=',
                Session::get('personnel_info.0')->box_id)
                ->whereBetween('status', [1, 2])
                ->where('view_date', '=', Null)
                ->count();
        }
        $this->view->share('unreadMessage', $unreadMessage);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```php
<?php

namespace PTA_OIMS\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \PTA_OIMS\Http\Middleware\UnreadMessage::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \PTA_OIMS\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \PTA_OIMS\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \PTA_OIMS\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

    ];
}
```

Comment: use ` \Auth` from facade

Comment: Auth::check() returns a Boolean, not the user instance, you want to get the user with Auth::user() after the check.

Comment: This doesn’t belong in middleware. Middleware is for manipulating HTTP requests and responses. It’s more suited to be placed in a _view composer_: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use global `auth()` helper:

```
$user = auth()->check();
```

Comment: @RohullahRajaeeRad please show `app\Http\Kernel.php` you use.